# CAS Authentication Filter AngularJS

Tags: java, angularjs, cas

I am looking to implement CAS server for SSO for my angularJS front end application and Rest Backend application. I have configured the CAS 4.0 web app and the management webapp and they are working properly. The part I am confused about is how Angularjs and the UI- router should interact with the CAS authentication filter?? I am using the CAS login page for authentication and am not able to figure out how this would work. I have looked for any documentation on this and was not able to find any solution.

Could anyone provide any direction??

**EDIT**

As per suggestion adding more detail.

Angularjs application has 2 pages.

Landing page ---> Dashboard page

On the application configuration, I have set up a security configuration provided by https://objectpartners.com/2014/05/20/configuring-spring-security-cas-providers-with-java-config/

```
 @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.addFilter(casAuthenticationFilter()).authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/landing").permitAll().antMatchers("/dashboard")
            .authenticated().antMatchers("/dashboard/*").authenticated();
    http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(
            casAuthenticationEntryPoint());
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider());
}
```

MY cas url -  https://.../cas/login.

Added my app to cas management --  https://host:8443/myapp/#/dashboard/.*
Now my process should be

User---> Landing---->CAS Login-----> Dashboard

I am not sure what else needs to be configured from Angularjs perspective for the filter to catch the url change and redirect to CAS.

Comment: Suggest you ask more specific question(s). As it stands now question is far too broad. There are lots of tutorials around for SPA security and authentication practices as well as authentication modules for angular